# Declaring a useless local variable

Tags: java, if-statement, scope, declaration, local-variables

So this is an odd one, I know the code itself is fairly useless, but what I'm wondering why I get the error:

I was writing some code, I had written this:

```
if(scan.hasNextInt())
    int row = scan.nextInt();
```

Wasn't thinking about variable scope at the time, obviously this is useless because I can't use `row` past the `if` anyway. What I don't get is why I got the error I did:

```
> javac hw.java
hw.java:25: '.class' expected
    int row = scan.nextInt();
        ^
hw.java:25: not a statement
    int row = scan.nextInt();
    ^    
hw.java:25: illegal start of expression
    int row = scan.nextInt();
            ^
hw.java:25: ';' expected
    int row = scan.nextInt();
                  ^
```

Now if I just modify that if check to:

```
if(scan.hasNextInt()) {
    int row = scan.nextInt();
}
```

It will compile fine. I was under the impression that if there was 1 line under the `if` the curly brackets were optional... clearly there are other considerations as well or both would either compile or fail.

Could someone explain to me, or point me to a document that explains why I can't declare a local variable under the `if` conditional without the curly brackets?

---

**EDIT:** Here's the full function:

```
public static char getinput() {
    System.out.println("Where do you want to go? (row column)");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(scan.hasNextInt())
        int row = scan.nextInt();
    String input = scan.next();
    System.out.println(input);
    return 'a';    
}
```

Comment: what comes before and after that `if`?

Comment: Please write your complete code here

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have a `if`, `for`, `while`, `do/while` you must follow it with a statement.  A declaration is not a statement.

From [JLS 14.9 - The if Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9)

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement

IfThenElseStatement:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement

IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
    if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
```

I assume they do this because any variable you declare couldn't be used as it would be out of scope immediately (except the same declaration)

Comment: There it is. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not 100% sure, but this sentence from [JLS 14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) might be more relevant - "Every local variable declaration statement is _immediately contained by a block_." (emphasis added)

Comment: Changing the `if` to a `while` results in the same error, so actually I'm pretty sure that's the rule in effect

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that a declaration isn't an executable statement and a declaration with an assignment is really broken into two different statements by the compiler, with the first statement (the declare) not being executable.  An if requires an executable construct, either a block or an executable statement.

I know that I've not been able to put a breakpoint on a non-sassignment declaration statement in the Eclipse debugger.  Probably the same underlying reason.