# Different with or without body scope of 'IF' Statement

Tags: java

This is simple but it's getting confuse me, I learnt about body scope is
**first line of break point,**   But below 1'st `if` statement getting error (*Not a statement*) and 2'nd is fine.

I just want only, why getting error?

```
if (true)
    String name="Body Test";
```

And

```
if (true) {
    String name="Body Test";
}
```

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression 
 Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment 
 Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement String cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: It's unable to compile.

Comment: What is the compilation error? It doesn't just not compile, it gives you the reason it doesn't compile, and points to the line of the errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956191/declaring-a-useless-local-variable

Answer (score 4):

`if (true) String name="Body Test";` is invalid since the introduction of a new variable into scope *cannot* be conditional, as it's something that happens at *compile time*. Note that Java is not clever enough to realise that the `if (true)` will *always* run. The other way you've written it is absolutely fine since the `{` and `}` *always* enclose `name`.

It's somewhat akin to introducing a new variable in a particular `case` of a `switch` block, without using `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 4):

In your example you are trying to declare a local variable `name` using [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause). As in Oracle documentation [Local Variable Declaration Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) is said:

> Every local variable declaration statement is **immediately contained by a block**.

Also from [The if Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) ducmentation it has the following syntax:

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

while in the Java Specification [list of statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) there are **no declarations**.

And defining a variable within the scope of a single-statement block (without braces) makes it unreachable outside the scope. As in your first case where declaration is not contained in a `{}` block, so compiler gives an error.

This is only about declaration, in the case of initialization it works:

```
String name;              // declaration
if (true)
   name = "Body Test";    // initialization (compiles okay)
```

as well as code below will fail by compiler:

```
if (true)
    String name;          // only declaration (compile error!)
```

At the same time [Google Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces) as the best practice advice to use braces with `if`, `else`, `for`, `do` and `while` statements **always**, even when the body is empty or contains only a single statement. Braces improve the uniformity and readability of code.

Comment: You don't answer the question here, the question is why do we get a compilation error with the first case (which proves that they are not fully equivalent )

Comment: Yes exactly @Nicolas, why can not create local variable in first case.

Comment: "So in the first case your declaration is not contained in a block and compiler gives an error.". It *is* contained within a scope block. The problem is due to the fact that it's introduction is *conditional* on the evaluation of `if`.

Comment: Thanks @DimaSan, one question **String name="Body Test";** is one statement ?

Comment: @Chump Block that is code enclosed between the `{` and `}` braces. From that point of view it's outside block.

Comment: @Vinod Yes it is one declaration statement that initializes the variable `name` with a value `Body test`.

Comment: Yes, Why not declaration statement in first case?, because if statement allow one statement without body { }.

Comment: No, the declaration is not allowed there. If you write `if (true) String name;` you'll also get a compiler error, despite the `String name` is declaration only.

Comment: I agree with you, why not declare one statement without body? –

Comment: @Vinod I edited my answer with some JSL info, please read it. Btw you have brought up a very interesting and important question, I didn't know about it before - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example String name="Body Test"; is **block statement**. You can only put **a statement** without curly braces. Please read this Oracle's official site for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2

Answer (score 0):

```
if (true)
    String name="Body Test";
```

Above code block throws an error saying **variable declaration not allowed here**

because compiler allows only one statement after **if(true)** where a declaration is invalid because of the scope of that variables.

```
if (true) {
String name="Body Test";
}
```

But in the second case there is a chance of multiple lines of code so no error.

Comment: In the first case **String name="Body Test";** is one statement, So why not declaration allow?

Comment: As I mentioned, declaring a variable is meaning less because we can't use it further in the code.

You can use the following code,
String name;
        if (true)
            name="Body Test";

Comment: I agree with you, it's not matter further use. Matter is that why not declare one statement without body?

Comment: Then someone may ask why we declare a useless variable ?
Also compiler understand that this may be a bug.

Comment: are you clear about this ? these are some patterns used by java compiler to avoid some unnecessary  codes and bugs.